# '" "' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, sdk, android-sdk-tools

When trying to run android.Bat  file (SDK MAnager), I'm getting the following error:

> '" "' is not recognized as an internal or external command

looks like I have a space somwhere , isn't it? 
the thing is that I have no idea where.
The SDK path is : C:\Android\android-sdk\tools

in Environement Variables I'm forwarind to JAVA_HOME and the value is : C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jre7\bin

it looks that the problem comes from somewhere else.

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` shouldn't have `\bin` on the end, that bit should be in the `PATH` instead: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: You mean delete Java_home and add it as you mentioned in the PATH?

Comment: Got u.I did it but still having the same error